# How do I show a progress bar with the actual percentage of progress of my background worker?

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a background worker that executes 2 functions, and I don't know if there is a way to measure how much does it takes to complete the process.

For example:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    table1 = function1;
    table2 = function2;
}
```

I have found this

```
int total = 100; //some number (this is your variable to change)!!

for (int i = 0; i <= total; i++) //some number (total)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);                
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
}
```

Which is not representative to the progress rate, I have seen the progress bar fill and restart again and the work ends somewhere along the second or third "run"

I want the progress bar to actually show how much is done in %
is that possible or I have to guess by trial and run?

Comment: Here's a [complete example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-implement-a-form-that-uses-a-background-operation) of how to implement a winform that uses a background worker and reports progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this in an automatic way (as up to my knowledge).
It is you as a programmer who defines the progress represented in a progress bar.

The usual example is a background process iterating a large array. The progress bar is updated, for example, in 10% portions when the background proces is done with every 1/10th of an array. Or in 5% portions for every 1/20th of an array and so on. For an example of this you can refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-implement-a-form-that-uses-a-background-operation) provided by @SergeyShevchenko in the comments.

At the very least (in a not very representative way though) you could decree that the first function comprises approximately 50% (20? 80%?) of the whole work and update the progress bar accordingly after the first function is done before calling the second function.

Another approach would be to change the two functions (if it is possible and reasonable) in a way that they're able to report their progress, then you would be able to translate the reported progress into ProgressBar state.